# EditText doesn't want me to type number, jumps back to previous textfield

Tags: android

There is list row with 2 edit texts, one for name and another for value, problem is when cursor is set up for value field, it bounces to first field immediately, with no chance to type anything there. Here's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="176dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/valueID"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Value"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameID"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="176dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/xButtonID"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/valueID"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="176dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Here is Java code for getView, there is actually  nothing interesting, no listeners, no actions..:

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        SheetItem sheetItem = new SheetItem();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(listItemLayout,parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameID);
            holder.value = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.valueID);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.item = getItem(position);



        ImageButton deleteButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.xButtonID);
        deleteButton.setTag(position);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                itemList.remove(pos);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: show the java code, do you have any listeners placed for the second editText?

Comment: You can see for my updated question

Comment: Try to use these attributes android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: still doesn't change behavior :(

Comment: If possible change your parent layout to relative or linear(horizontal) and retry. let me know what happens.

Comment: what about this messages when I press value field?  IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Comment: This is a probable debug message from the keyboard you are using.

Comment: Change the layout as I told you and remove imeOtions from both. Let's check out all the wayout one by one.

Comment: Still happens the same

Comment: Did you solve this @Patroy?

Comment: @BaluSangem unfortunately not, are you experiencing the same?

Comment: @Patroy no i just used your code (from question) and its working. Can you share me your code ?

Comment: @BaluSangem if you would like to see all my code here is git repository of it: https://github.com/PatrykDampc/CalcuNotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey just add one tag to Activity element in Manifest file

it is working fine

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

thanks for sharing project.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of problem better long press that specific edit text and look for the options. It provides some thing like input-type then select the appropriate one. I guess that should do.